Understanding property in weaviate class
The signature of the weaviate config property is as follows:
wvc.config.Property(
    *,
    name: str,
    data_type: weaviate.collections.classes.config.DataType,
    description: Optional[str] = None,
    index_filterable: Optional[bool] = None,
    index_searchable: Optional[bool] = None,
    nested_properties: Union[weaviate.collections.classes.config.Property, List[weaviate.collections.classes.config.Property], NoneType] = None,
    skip_vectorization: bool = False,
    tokenization: Optional[weaviate.collections.classes.config.Tokenization] = None,
    vectorize_property_name: bool = True,
) -> None

where:
skip_vectorization:Whether to skip vectorization of the property. Defaults to `False`.
and
vectorize_property_name : Whether to vectorize the property name. Defaults to `True`.
A vector DB is a mapping of vectors to these objects that have multiple properties. What is the use of vectorizing the property and the property name via the arguments skip_vectoriszation the property vectorize_property_name

Duda from Weaviate here! Those options will allow you to have properties and/or properties name that will not be part of the resulting vectorization.
Check here, for example, how the vectorization of an object in Weaviate works:
https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/config-refs/schema#configure-semantic-indexing
For instance:
Unless specified otherwise in the schema, the default behavior is to:

Only vectorize properties that use the text data type (unless skipped)
Sort properties in alphabetical (a-z) order before concatenating values
If vectorizePropertyName is true (false by default) prepend the property name to each property value
Join the (prepended) property values with spaces
Prepend the class name (unless vectorizeClassName is false)
Convert the produced string to lowercase

For example, this data object,
Article = {
  summary: "Cows lose their jobs as milk prices drop",
  text: "As his 100 diary cows lumbered over for their Monday..."
}

will be vectorized as:

article cows lose their jobs as milk prices drop as his 100 diary cows
lumbered over for their monday...

So if you choose to vectorize the property name, on the above case summary and textyou will add those informations to the vector as well. If that was the case, your vector payload would be :

article summary cows lose their jobs as milk prices drop text as his 100 diary cows lumbered over for their monday...

Let me know if that helps?

This was definitely helpful. Thank you for your time :)
